# Exact ODEs and if $f_x\, dx + f_y \,dy = 0$ then $f(x,y)$ is a constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

In explaining a method to solve exact first-order linear differential equations, one uses the fact that if $f_x\,dx + f_y\,dy = 0$ then $f(x,y)$ is a constant. But the function $f(x,y)$ always turns out to be like $z = x^2 - xy + 2y^2$. It's never something like $z = 10$. So, what do they mean by $f(x,y)$ is a constant? Maybe I'm just very confused now and this is something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, *constant* means that for any solution $y = g(x)$ of the differential equation, $f$ is constant on the graph $\{(x, g(x))\} \subset \Bbb R^2$, that is, that
$$x \mapsto f(x, g(x))$$ is a constant function. This does not mean that $f(x, y)$ (which unlike the previous function has two arguments) is itself a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

If $z(x,y)$ is taken constant for any level curve of intersection $ z= $ constant, consider the total differential which gives:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} =-\frac{\partial f /\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}  $$